# bash while loop iterating 1 extra time

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I get a file `input.txt` or URLs by running this in /etc/drush/

```
ls /etc/drush | grep test  | sed s/.alias.drushrc.php//g | sed '/^$/d' > input.txt
```

I feed that into a loop like this:

```
while read a; do
    echo "url: $a"
done < input.txt
```

or like this:

```
cat input.txt | while read a; do
    echo "url: $a"
done
```

I always get one extra "url: " at the end, and have verified there is no blank line. I confirmed with

```
cat input.txt
```

Any ideas what's causing the extra iteration?

input.txt looks like this:

```
www.first.com
www.something.com
www.something.com
www.last.com
```

output looks like this

```
url: www.first.com
url: www.something.com
url: www.something.com
url: www.last.com
url:
```

Comment: Can you add in your question what you get for results and what you are expecting?

Comment: dos line ending? `cat -vET input.txt`

Comment: You'd need to provide a byte-for-byte example of input that causes this for the question to be actionable. A line with hidden characters at the end is more likely than the posited `read` that behaves contrary to specified behavior.

Comment: ...so, on a system with GNU cat, you could `cat -A input.txt`, or (elsewhere) `od -ax <input.txt`, but until you tell us how to create an input.txt that causes your problem, we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: See the example at http://ideone.com/EW6kaa of the code you gave working perfectly with an `input.txt` that has no unusual line endings, no blank endline, etc.

Comment: Nobody asked you to disclose the contents. We just need a snippet that reproduces the problem.

Comment: that's almost my complete script. `ls` line to get contents, then the loop. running that exact things always outputs an extra line. I don't know what other info I can provide

Comment: @RichardN, you could provide code you've tested to create a version of input.txt that demonstrates your problem. It doesn't need to be the exact / literal content you're using, but it has to create a `input.txt` that causes the problem when run.

Comment: There's a reason we didn't ask you to run `cat input.txt`, but instead `cat -A input.txt` or `cat -vET input.txt` (depending on your version of `cat`) or `od -ax <input.txt`; `cat` alone with no options doesn't show you hidden characters, so you'll need to add whichever options your operating system's version of `cat` provides to show hidden characters.

Comment: cat -A returns all lines with a `$` on the end

Comment: @RichardN, did you observe the working copy of the code behind the ideone.com link? Can you cause the failure you asked this question about to occur there? As long as this is something than only happens for you and nobody else, it's hard to fix.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy did you notice that code doesn't output the last URL?

Comment: @RichardN, I didn't, but that's what you would expect from a file with no trailing newline; if the last character of the file is text rather than a newline, the `read` will load that text into `a` but return an exit status indicating failure. So I take that to mean that the `stdin` field at ideone.com doesn't presume an implicit trailing newline (which most UNIX text editors and tools will add automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a lot better than

```
ls /etc/drush | grep test  | sed s/.alias.drushrc.php//g | sed '/^$/d' > input.txt
```

The following is purely in-process -- no external commands anywhere -- and thus faster and less bug-prone:

```
files=( /etc/drush/*test* )  # glob-expand to generate a list of full paths
files=( "${files[@]##*/}" )  # remove everything up to and including the last '/'
files=( "${files[@]//.alias.drushrc.php/}" ) # remove .alias.drushrc.php from names
for url in "${files[@]}"; do # iterate over names in the array
  echo "url: $url"
done
```

If `.alias.drushrc.php` is an extension rather than something which could be found anywhere in the file's name, you might instead write that line as:

```
files=( "${files[@]%.alias.drushrc.php}" )
```

To understand the expressions here, see [BashFAQ #73 (on parameter expansion, the technique used here)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) or [BashFAQ #100 (on native string manipulation in bash in general)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

---

To appreciate why the original version is buggy, you might start with [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and additionally note that newlines are valid characters inside filenames on POSIX systems.

Comment: Thanks for being helpful! The dynamic array build is something I hadn't figured out yet, thus the text file. Now I'm just trying to figure out the proper syntax to pass a variable in place of `test` and I'm set. Thanks again!

Comment: That would be `files=( /etc/drush/*"$foo"* )`, to substitute the contents of the variable `foo`.

Comment: @RichardN, it's actually safer with the quotes exactly as given (around the variable expansion, but *not* around the globs) -- otherwise substrings with spaces, literal glob characters, or characters in the IFS variable as currently defined won't work correctly.

Comment: thanks for that. Would you mind providing a quick explanation or link as to what the first two lines are actually doing?

Comment: I've tried to add relevant details, and have thrown in a few links to relevant parts of the Wooledge BashFAQ.

Answer (score 0):

The extra iteration is probably because your input file has a blank line at the end.  You can check with something like `tail -n 3 input.txt | od -ax`.

I would recommend checking for blank lines within the loop:

```
while read a; do
    if [[ -z "$a" ]]; then continue; fi
    echo "url: $a"
done < input.txt
```

The `-z` checks returns true if the following string is zero-length.  If it is, we have the while loop skip that iteration.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: the unnecessary use of cat. `done <input.txt` is the best practice here.

Comment: I must be uninformed.  Where is that stated as the best practice?  I always figured `commands | while read` was always cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: Creating a pipeline means you have an implicit subshell. It has a high performance cost, and also means that your code can't have side effects on the parent process -- try setting or updating a variable inside your loop, and you'll see it's gone when the loop exits.

Comment: ...see http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Also, note that you can write `< input.txt while read a; do` if you really want to see the input at the beginning of the command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Ha!  I never ran into that issue because, incidentally, I primarily use KSH88.  If process substitution was more portable I'd be using that as a solution instead.  Thanks for the heads up though.